# Is it possible to fetch facebook user's profile without logging using facebook connect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebooker, facebook-fql

Basically, I want to fetch facebook profile avatars onto my application since I am using their login to create a particular record. How do we display their profile pic without actually forcing the user to connect into facebook to retrieve these pictures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the fbml fb:profile-pic tag or you can use the users.getinfo API call without the user logging in, however it will then use the default "everyone" privacy level for the pictures you're trying to get.